# Is it unprofessional to use @media screen in css

Tags: css, media-queries, responsiveness

I am trying to make my site responsive and was originally planning on using `@media screen` property in CSS, in order to optimise it for mobile devices.

I'm already using bootstrap but want to modify parts of it (which I have been doing using `@media screen`) for mobile devices. However, I've been told that this is unprofessional and that I should avoid using this. Is this true?

Thanks

Comment: You're on the wrong site for this question, but there's nothing inherently wrong with media queries.

Comment: not really because bootstrap also uses media Queries to make your site responsive and i also use it often because i have to change the custom design that i make which is not possible with bootstrap

Comment: Without knowing what the person that told you that exactly meant, it is not possible to tell you why the person said that. Probably the person didn't say that using `@media screen` is unprofessional, but the way you used it in combination with bootstrap was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to fathom why someone would tell you that using `@media screen` is unprofessional. That's how media queries work for, ya know, screens.

No, there is absolutely no reason to think that using media queries for `screen`, `print`, or `speech` is unprofessional in any way. It's a necessary tool in your web dev toolkit and you should feel free to use it as intended for your responsive websites.

See here for Mozilla's documentation for using media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

**UPDATE**

Based on the update to your question (where you added that you are using Bootstrap), I would tend to agree with @aaron-mcguire's answer below.

As he alluded to, it's impossible to discern exactly the context in which your friend/colleague/person told you it would be unprofessional to use `@media screen`. But if you're using Bootstrap, it probably makes sense to customize Bootstrap's built-in grid system in order to best meet your layout needs.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very wide question, the answer to the whole question would be no - it's not unprofessional to use media queries, they are a fundamental part of the responsive development process. Where the question becomes a little jaded is when you mention you are using bootstrap.

As others have mentioned Bootstrap also uses media queries: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/

Since we have no context or design to go off it's hard to assume whether or not you would be fine using the preexisting media queries built into Bootstrap or if you would need to define your own.

Perhaps the person you were talking to has said it was unprofessional using custom media queries in place of bootstraps built in ones. Which again is hard for us to judge without seeing code/design. I would say unprofessional is the wrong choice of words - if you're trying to optimise your website on a mobile device then it's probably more a question of - is it the most efficient thing creating custom media queries in place of using the `@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { ... }` one.

But again take my answer with a pinch of salt because there is no real context to the question. Web development is a constant learning process there is always somebody who is going to tell you that something you are doing isn't *the* correct way.